# 32-bit process failed to get another 32-bit process's PEB on Windows10 x64 system

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory, wow64

Code:

```cpp
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

WCHAR lpCmdline[] = L"ad.exe";
if (!CreateProcess(
    NULL,
    lpCmdline,
    NULL, NULL, TRUE,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    wprintf(L"Create process fail: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi = { 0 };
NtQueryInformationProcessFn pNtQueryInformationProcess = (NtQueryInformationProcessFn) \
    GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"ntdll"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");

ULONG dwRead;
if (NT_ERROR(pNtQueryInformationProcess(
    pi.hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation,
    &pbi, sizeof pbi, &dwRead))) {
    wprintf(L"Call NtQueryInformationProcess error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

PEB peb = { 0 };
SIZE_T stRead;
if (!ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof PEB, NULL)) {
    wprintf(L"Call ReadProcessMemory fail: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

return 0;
```

Compiled as x86 binary, and the `ad.exe` is also x86 binary. System is Windows10 64-bit

```
PS C:\> .\t.exe
Call ReadProcessMemory fail: 6
PS C:\> file .\t.exe
.\t.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
PS C:\> file .\ad.exe
.\ad.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Comment: Well, error code 6 is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`... Your code works for me on Win10-64, for 32-bit executables

Comment: So weird. I have tested on 2 machines, they both returned error code 6. I wonder if there's any way I can debug for reason

Comment: Your code also works for me. My environment is the same as yours. Have you tried other 32-bit executable programs?

Comment: Debugging suggestion: print `pi.hProcess` before and after your call to `pNtQueryInformationProcess()` to make sure it didn't get corrupted for some reason. Also, can you make sure that the version of `"ad.exe"` on the failing systems is in fact 32-bit?

Comment: Yes, I have tried other 32-bit executable, they are both error

Comment: I think you are right, the `pi.hProcess` has been corrupted after function calling. I have print `pi.hProcess` before and after calling `pNtQueryInformationProcess`, the first output is `000000F4` and the second is `00AFF000`. Why does this function calling change the value of `pi.hProcess` (isn't the `pi.hProcess` passed as a copy value?)

Comment: Found the reason, I forgot to specify the function calling convention. Thank you for your help!